# How to extract the texture of a mesh to an image file

Tags: textures, kinect, texture-mapping

I'm look for a method to extract whole data from a PLY file to a image file like png or bmp.

Look: I have the mesh bellow:
[mesh image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2QbU.jpg)

How can I extract the image file from that? Just like this:

[example of result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2k64.png)

Someone can help me please?